# Is there a way to make custom path effects in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas

I'd like to make an Android app that will display a drawing of lines and I'd like to make something beautiful (big challenge).

Basically the app will show a drawing based on x y coordinates. The result must be identical to another drawing in a web based app. For the web based app, we'll be using [this library](http://projects.mattytemple.com/html5/harmony/).

I know how to draw paths on a canvas in an Android app but I don't know how to apply a custom effect on it. I've noticed I could use a [PathEffect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathEffect.html) with this method:

```
paint.setPathEffect(myEffect);
```

but I'm not sure how to create another effect than the available ones (ComposePathEffect, CornerPathEffect, DashPathEffect, DiscretePathEffect, PathDashPathEffect, SumPathEffect).

Any tips and help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to look in the source code of these path effects and understand how do they work, what's the idea, and derive how you could make your own path effect.

Comment: Funny thing I've just thought about that and the source code is not looking so complicated. I might end up with this solution.

Comment: I have not been able to find the custom path effect source code. It's done with the NDK. Do you happen to have a link?